# Visual Studio Error: You are not logged into Windows Live Messenger

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, live

Does anyone know why visual studio does this?

Comment: I have never experienced that. When and how does it occur?

Comment: Looks like a Windows Live Messenger error, not a Visual Studio one.

Comment: A quick google found this? [http://shortfastcode.blogspot.com/2009/12/visual-studio-error-you-are-not-logged.html](http://shortfastcode.blogspot.com/2009/12/visual-studio-error-you-are-not-logged.html)

Answer (score 6):

If you are using TFS try this:

1. Open VS 2008 and wait until Team Members is not "working..."
2. Right-click on "Team Members" and select Personal Settings
3. Under Collaboration, click Change
4. On the opened dialog select None and click OK
5. Click OK once again

Comment: ****, and I was hoping to get my first accepted answer... He is not coming back, is he? :)